# Rule for stabbing through multiple enemies with piercing weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e

A fellow party-member of mine wanted to stab through 2 kobolds with a longsword, and my DM came up with a quick rule (disadvantage on attack role and half damage to the second kobold). This rule seems fair to me, but I was wandering if there is a good way to go about calculating damage for stabbing through multiple enemies?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se. Please take our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). After posting the answer, I've re-read the question and it's unclear if you are asking about official rules content or you are just asking for ideas about how to calculate it. If you are looking for ideas, RPG.se might not be the best place for it, and it would probably be a better question for an [RPG discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/43856), like the ones in the linked question.

Comment: Also, the Longsword isn't a piercing weapon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## You can only attack more than one creature at a time if something allows you to.

The Attack action is single target. A few features, such as Horde Breaker and Whirlwind Attack, from the Ranger's Hunter subclass, allow you to attack more than one target, for example.

> **Horde Breaker**: Once on each of your turns when you make a weapon attack, you can make another attack with the same weapon against a different creature that is within 5 feet of the original target and within range of your weapon.
>
> **Whirlwind Attack**: You can use your action to make a melee attack against any number of creatures within 5 feet of you, with a separate attack roll for each target.

Note that these texts specify that each attack is a different attack roll with different damage.

An optional ruling for **Cleaving** is given in the DMG, p. 272, which states:

> When a melee attack reduces an undamaged creature
> to 0 hit points, any excess damage from that attack
> might carry over to another creature nearby. The
> attacker targets another creature within reach and, if
> the original attack roll can hit it, applies any remaining
> damage to it. If that creature was undamaged and is
> likewise reduced to 0 hit points, repeat this process,
> carrying over the remaining damage until there are no
> valid targets, or until the damage carried over fails to
> reduce an undamaged creature to 0 hit points.

This is similar to the example house rule/ruling, but it requires one creature to soak up most of the damage before another creature gets any.  You could say that the "on the spot" ruling was a variation on *Cleaving.*

Comment: Something else that might be relevant (if you want to include it) is the subclass-specific features of the Hunter (Ranger subclass): Horde Breaker and Whirlwind Attack.

Comment: @V2Blast added them as examples for my first point. Thanks :)

Comment: Great answer in terms of identifying game features that work similarly, but the question is asking about a house rule. (The DMG citation seems to answer very solidly).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Well to be fair the reason I voted it as unclear was because I didn't understand if they wanted to know "what are the actual rules for it?" or "how should I house rule it?" - the second being idea generation = closed.

Comment: Indeed, I like the way you put together the response, as it covers more than one approach to the same thing: a bit of "what is a standard game feature" and "what is an already available optional rule in DMG.  (+1 already awarded).  What do you think of the edit?  If you like it, good, if not, roll it back.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what HellSaint and V2Blast found, there's atleast two more relevant features.

Arcane archer fighters from XGE can learn this arcane shot option:

> **Piercing Arrow.**
>   You use transmutation magic to give your arrow an ethereal quality. When you use this option, you don't make an attack roll for the attack. Instead, the arrow shoots forward in a line, which is 1 foot wide and 30 feet long, before disappearing. The arrow passes harmlessly through objects, ignoring cover. Each creature in that line must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes damage as if it were hit by the arrow, plus an extra 1d6 piercing damage. On a successful save, a target takes half as much damage.
>   The piercing damage increases to 2d6 when you reach 18th level in this class.

Battle master fighters can also learn this laughably weak maneuver:

> **Sweeping Attack.**
>   When you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to damage another creature with the same attack. Choose another creature within 5 feet of the original target and within your reach. If the original attack roll would hit the second creature, it takes damage equal to the number you roll on your superiority die. The damage is of the same type dealt by the original attack.

It's worth noting that both the Piercing Arrow and the Sweaping Attack consume resources to perform.

**Bonus tip:**
In my experience, flavorful descriptions in combat go a long way. If during one turn I kill an enemy and attack another, I'll often describe it all as one mighty blow that cleaved the first enemy and struck the second! Your party-member can just as easily narrate stabbing through 2 kobolds in similar scenarios.